# Custom style not working for MUI textfield React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to give custom theme for MUI textfield component.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: "red"
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

function mycomp(){
  return(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <TextField
          sx={{ width: "80%" }}
          id="template-name"
          name="template"
          label="Template Name"
          type="text"
          variant="standard"
          helperText="Specify a name for the template in format"
        />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

But no color change in textfield. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` is made up of different parts. The part you need to select for text color is the `input` tag. And you can do that with:

```
styleOverrides: {
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputBase-input": { color: "red" },
  },
},
```

You can see a list of things you can select in [this doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input-base/#css).