# Material-ui: Can I resize datepicker height?

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, height

I'm now woking on Material-ui datepicker and I want to make height of datepicker smaller.

[image]

I tried giving the `"size"` prop of TextField or IconButton of a datepicker as `"small"`, but it didn't work the way I intended to. I want to resize the height like `sx={{height: '35px'}}`, not using the `"size"` prop. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextField` is made up of different parts.
You need to select the `input` tag inside it.

```
<TextField sx={{ "& .MuiInputBase-input": { height: "100px" } }} />
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74835560/5613027) for another example.